# PS3 controller with Unity on Mac

Tags: unity, playstation3

I am trying to use my PS3 Controller with Unity but it has been unsuccessful.

I followed this video to do so:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcettC1QHu4

I have done the same thing as the video but for some reason unity is not getting ANY input from the controller.

I have tested the controller with another commercial game on my Mac and it works perfectly, so my controller is well connect to my computer.

here is a screenshot of the input manager:[image]

**joystick button 0** is the **X button**

Comment: your following a computer tutorial on a mac.. its probably just a matter of using the wrong inputs due to using the wrong drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Controllers and platforms have always been a tricky subject. I would suggest you to give a try to InControl ( [unmaintained open source version](https://github.com/pbhogan/InControl) or [paid version from the Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14695) ). It's a great plug-in, and it knows how to handle several types of game controller on various platforms.

Comment: For users today, I'd recommend Unity's new Input System package, which is much more powerful and robust than the old Input Manager, and available at no extra cost.